# CarouselPage with progress indicator?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

I have a registration page that has too many fields, that requires me to divide it into 4 pages, 
I thought that the best experience is to have a `CarouselPage` with four `ContentPage`s, that can be easily navigate through, and yet having one view with a corresponding view model.
Before asking the main question, I want to make sure that I'm taking the right decision, and I didn't miss any other option that is dedicated for such case that I'm not aware of (I'm still in my first steps in Xamarin).
if the `CarouselPage` is the way to go, then I want to have some indicator on the bottom of the screen, that shows the registration progress like a progress bar that increases by 25% on every next page, something that ties all the `ContentPage`s together

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CarouselView which is the successor of CarouselPage. There is a documentation how to implement [CarouseView](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView) and here is nice [blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/).

I can give you good idea how to start. CarouselViev is similar to ListView.

```
<controls:CarouselViewControl 
    x:Name="MyCarouselView">
    <controls:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Entry 
                    Placeholder="{Binding FirstEntryName}"
                    Text="{Binding FirstEntryText, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding FirstEntryVisible}" />
                <Entry 
                    Placeholder="{Binding SecondEntryName}"
                    Text="{Binding FirstEntryText, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding SecondEntryVisible}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</controls:CarouselViewControl>
```

Then you can populate ItemSource with ObservableCollection DataFromEntries and MyViewData looks like this:

```
public class MyViewData
{
    public string FirstEntryName { get; set; }
    public string FirstEntryText { get; set; }
    public bool FirstEntryVisible { get; set; }
    public string SecondEntryName { get; set; }
    public string SecondEntryText { get; set; }
    public bool SecondEntryVisible { get; set; }
}
```

To enable Indicator you need to set property ShowIndicators to true.